# Relaciones en Laravel Elocuent con varias condiciones

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relaciones

tengo el siguiente problema.
Tengo un modelo de elocuent (cashBox) que tiene un campo de tipo fecha donde guarda su última revisión, este modelo esta relacionado con otro que representa un servicio ejecutado. Deseo tener una relacion que devuelva los servicios relacionados con esa caja que se ejecutaron despues de la ultima revicion.
He intentado algo como esto

```
public function serviceLogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ServiceLog::class)
        ->whereDate('checked_at','>',$this->cash_register_at);
}
```

En teoria daberia funcionar porque he intentado algo parecido otras veces pero con valores estaticos opara comparar. El principal problema es que el `$this->cash_register_at` retorna vacio. Parece que en el metodo de la relacion no puedo acceder al objeto.
Puedo obtener la información que deseo con Constructor de consultas de laravel y haciendo uso de joins etc. pero el objetivo es obtener un codigo reutilizable y lo mas limpio posible
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: 'cash_register_at' es un campo del modelo de tipo datetime. Debe tener la ultima ves que se hizo un cierre de caja

Comment: Normalmente eloquent  lo usa como una opropiedad "mágica" ccreo que se le llama que representa una propiedad en base de datos

Comment: Ok, ya te entiendo mejor y creo que tienes razón pero esperaba que tomase el valor del modelo de alguna forma, al fin y al cabo no es un metodo estatico. Pero por lo que veo se ejecuta en un modelo vacio

Comment: Voy a intentar proveer una respuesta pero antes necesito saber que valor debería tener `$this->cash_register_at`

Comment: Debe tener una fecha

Comment: Si "el objetivo es obtener un codigo reutilizable" puedes hacerte un [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) con eager loading y poniendo el `where` ahí, o con el join que muestras en tu respuesta.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ animate a colocarlo como respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtube respuesta a mi problema asi

```
public function serviceLogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ServiceLog::class)
        ->join('cash_boxes', 'service_logs.checked_at', '>', 'cash_boxes.cash_register_at')
        ->select('service_logs.*');
}
```

Espero que pueda serle util a alguien. En lo personal no es totalmente de mi agrado la solucion y estoy a la escucha de variantes. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo definida la relación de esta manera:

```
public function serviceLogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ServiceLog::class);
}
```

Luego, podrías hacer que en la relación devuelva los servicios relacionados con esa caja que se ejecutaron después de la ultima revisión con una consulta como ésta:

```
CashBox::with([
    'serviceLogs' => function($query) {
        return $query->whereDate('service_logs.checked_at','>','cash_boxes.cash_register_at');
    }
])->first();
```

Ahora, si *"el objetivo es obtener un codigo reutilizable"*, puedes hacerte un [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) poniendo el `with` y el `where` ahí (o con el join que muestras en tu respuesta):

```
public function scopeServiceLogsAfterLastRevision ($query)
{
    return $query->with([
        'serviceLogs' => function($query) {
            return $query->whereDate('service_logs.checked_at','>','cash_boxes.cash_register_at');
        }
    ]);
}
```

Y en la consulta lo utilizas así:

```
CashBox::serviceLogsAfterLastRevision()->first();
```

Comment: Me gusta tu respuesta pero me trae un problema que habia obtenido al probar otras soluciones. Lanza una exepcion.Incorrect DATE value: 'cash_boxes.cash_register_at' (SQL: select * from `service_logs` where `service_logs`.`cash_box_id` in (1) and date(`service_logs`.`checked_at`) > cash_boxes.cash_register_at)".

Comment: Es como si tomase el segundo parametro del metodo whereData como un valor obligatopriamente y no como una columna. Tambien lo intente sustituyendo el whereData por un whereRaw pero no encuentra la columna

Comment: Ten en cuenta que es `whereDate` y no `whereData`. Si no, prueba con `whereColumn('service_logs.checked_at','>','cash_boxes.cash_register_at')`.

Comment: @AlejandroMoreno Otra cosa que también te puede servir es agregando la propiedad `$dates` a tus modelos: `protected $dates = ['checked_at'];` en ServiceLog, y `protected $dates = ['cash_register_at'];` en CashBox.